# An EmberJS DataStore adapter which supports HATEOAS

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data, hateoas, json-api

I'm creating an app which I'd really like to be quite RESTful that follows the [HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) REST requirement. On the front-end, I'm looking at using Ember because it seems pretty much in line with how I like to build front-end apps. Unfortunately though, the built-in REST DataSource Adapter doesn't seem to understand how to navigate APIs which follow HATEOAS - I have to specify data in terms of IDs, rather than via URLs.

Google isn't helping me - **does anybody know of a Data Adapter which *does* support HATEOAS?** If not, I'll try building one, but I didn't want to waste time!

Answer (score 0):

Ember Data strives to follow the [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/) spec, which came out of the formats that the REST adapter follows.

There are [two formats](http://jsonapi.org/format/), and while the ID-based format requires the client to have the URLs hard-coded for the resources, the URL-based format works with URL templates to include the links in the representations directly.